# Огромное количество непонятных таблиц

Tags: sql, oracle, sqldeveloper

только начал изучать SQL в Oracle среде. Столкнулся с тем, что при первом создании таблицы, она появляется, но ее буквально очень трудно найти в длинном списке каких-то непонятных таблиц, которые я не создавал (я знаю, что можно находить таблицы через поиск, через фильтр и т.д., но допустим, у меня большое количество таблиц и я точно не могу вспомнить даже название необходимой таблицы). Так вот сам вопрос, что мне делать, как упростить взаимодействие? Могу ли я просто удалить все эти непонятные таблицы и не полетит ли все? Знаю, возможно вопросы глупые, но я не очень понимаю, что стоит делать, а что нет, а в гайдах ничего про это не пишут. Можно ли вообще эти папки редактировать? Если нет, то как мне лучше всего сделать так, чтобы подсвечивались только созданные именно мной таблицы, а не те, которые уже были.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы залезли в чужую схему и спрашиваете как удалить множество непонятных таблиц, которые вам там мешаются? ))))  Создайте свою схему, и логиньтесь под ней, и по умолчанию девелопер будет показывать вам только ваши таблицы.

Comment: Это и есть моя схема, я создал свою базу данных, в оракле, а в ней вот... куча непонятных таблиц

Comment: как можно создать свою БД, не зная какие там таблицы?  вы откуда взяли скрипт её создания?  и зачем вы взяли именно его?

Comment: короче: редактировать список "папок" нельзя.  можно удалить таблицы.  можно создать ещё одну схему и работать там, перенеся туда только нужные таблицы, чтобы остальные не мешались